# What is this bizarre looking animal we found in the forest? Bug identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Please can someone identify this?

I can't find anything on the Internet like it. 2 cm long. [North Bohemian mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krkono%C5%A1e) ([Czech Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_Republic)).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That is the caterpillar of a [lobster moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobster_moth) (*Stauropus fagi*), family [Notodotidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notodontidae). It is mimicking a scorpion to help protect it from predation. An amazing insect.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81424/discussion-on-answer-by-karl-kjer-what-is-this-bizarre-looking-animal-we-found-i).